# Woher kommt der Ausspruch "Klopf, klopf!"

Tags: etymology, proverb, interjection

In meinem Umfeld gibt es mehrere Personen, die, wenn sie einen Raum betreten, der keine geschlossene Tür hat, anstatt zu klopfen laut

> Klopf, klopf!

rufen. Dabei ist eine eigentümliche Betonung auf dem ersten "Klopf" und ein Abfall der Tonhöhe auf dem zweiten "Klopf" bemerkenswert.

Nachdem die Personen voneinander unabhängig sind, und da sie auch aus verschiedenen Dialekträume stammen (Rheinland, Schwaben), frage ich mich, ob dieser Ausdruck eine gemeinsame Herkunft hat, es sich z.B. um ein Zitat handelt.

Ich bin nur auf die amerikanischen [*knock-knock jokes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knock-knock_joke) gestoßen, halte diese aber als Ursprung für weniger wahrscheinlich, da nie ein Witz eingeleitet wird, sondern es sich immer um einen Platzhalter für Klopfen an der Tür handelt.

Comment: Ich höre auch manchmal eine ansteigende Tonhöhe auf der zweiten Silbe. Dann ist das wohl die Anlautung einer *Frage, ob man reinkommen darf*.

Comment: Ich weiß es nicht sicher, aber ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass es damit zusammenhängt: In vielen Comics findet man solche verkürzten Indikativformen als lautmalerische Elemente. Diese wurden insbesondere von Dr. Erika Fuchs in ihren Übersetzungen der Disney-Comics verwendet. Diese Wortspielereien haben Einzug in den täglichen Sprachgebrauch gehalten und könnten die Herkunft von "Klopf! Klopf"" sein.
Eine Bedeutung der verwendeten Tonhöhe kenne ich nicht.

Comment: Gib uns die Telefonnummern der Personen, dann fragen wir sie. :)

Comment: Ich sag das auch und bei mir sagt die Tonhöhe aus, ob es ein Statement (Stimme senkt sich = hier bin ich!) oder eine Frage ist (Stimme geht hoch = Darf ich reinkommen?)

Comment: Die Witze gibt es auch auf Deutsch: http://www.witze-kiste.de/90,klopf-klopf-witze.html

Comment: Um mich (auch mit dem Fehrrad) durchzuschlängeln sag ich genre 'tüt-tüt'. Klappt prima.

Answer (score 1):

Auch wenn du den Zusammenhang als unwahrscheinlich siehst, halte ich tatsächlich die *Knock-knock*-Witze für den Ursprung. Ich habe sie mitte der Neunziger in England kennengelernt, da wurden sie nicht (mehr?) als amerikanischer Herkunft gesehen – wobei doch der eine oder andere Kalauer nur mit amerikanischer Mundart funktioniert, andere hingegen durchaus (oder vielleicht auch ausschließlich) mit englischer.

Damals sind auch ab und an Personen in Räume gekommen, und haben ihr Klopfen an der offenen Tür durch ein zusätzliches »Knock, knock!«, unterstrichen. Ich habe das sofort mit den Witzen assoziiert, aber die Hereinkommenden hatten in der Regel keinen Witz im Sinn.

Wenn ich schätzen müsste, würde ich davon ausgehen, dass in irgendeiner amerikanischen (Comedy-?) Serie eine Figur öfters »Knock, knock« sagt, wenn sie den Raum betritt, was in einer entsprechenden deutschen Synchronisation dann mangels Alternativen zu »klopf, klopf« wurde. Und dass es sich seither ausbreitet.

Comment: Könnte schon sein, aber dann wäre es super interessant, welche Serie das war. Mit Palim-Palim könnte ich z.B. sofort was anfangen, aber bei Klopf-Klopf kommt nichts